# Scipy strange results using curve fitting

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, curve-fitting

When I try to fit my data, results are a bit strange and I don't understand why ? Obtained fitting is flat, and the first input e=0. seems to raised a division error somewhere.
The only working case is when I modify e[0]=1.0e-9

The result is the following: 
[image]

From example [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/media.usm.maine.edu/~pauln/ScipyScriptRepo/CurveFitting.ipynb) it seems that my example is not so far from what I read, but I stay stuck, so could you help me please on what's going wrong in my case ?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

src_s = np.array((45.59,50.66664,59.74871,65.71018,72.76012,79.06256,84.13755,90.39944,
                  96.33653,101.65667,106.27968,110.76301,114.41808,117.21922,120.51836))
src_e = np.array((0.0,0.00126,0.00503,0.00804,0.01228,0.01685,0.02127,0.02846,0.03666,
                  0.04581,0.05620,0.06882,0.08005,0.09031,0.10327))
# plot source data
plt.plot(src_e, src_s, 'o')
# fitting function
def sigma(e, k ,n): return k*(e**n)
# find parameters curve fitting
param, var = curve_fit(sigma, src_e, src_s)
new_e = np.linspace(src_e.min(), src_e.max(), 50)
plt.plot(new_e, sigma(new_e, *param))

# modify first input
src_e[0]=1.0e-9
# relaunch parameters curve fitting
param, var = curve_fit(sigma, src_e, src_s)
new_e = np.linspace(src_e.min(), src_e.max(), 50)
plt.plot(new_e, sigma(new_e, *param))

plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please, explain "results are a bit strange and I don't understand why"

Comment: I added the image for you. Welcome to SO! ;)

Comment: Thank you my friend ;) Take a beer !

Comment: I've tested the code and if src_e[0]=0 is included (with its corresponding src_s[0] value) into the problem, the program yields "problem_curvefit.py:21: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in power
  return k*(e**n)+s0

Comment: Spyder doesn't report me any warning/error message ... whereas the console reports it :(

Answer (score 2):

The root of problem is an bad initial guess of parameters (actually no starting parameter is provided for `curve_fit`).

The target function can easily be linearized. Let's do that, then do a linear regression to get a good set of initial guess parameters for `curve_fit` (pass to it by `p0=`). The resulting fit is better (having less residue) and does not need to replace the first value of to be `1e-9`:

```
In [38]:

src_e[0]=1.0e-9
# relaunch parameters curve fitting
param, var = curve_fit(sigma, src_e, src_s)
new_e = np.linspace(src_e.min(), src_e.max(), 50)
src_e[0]=0
plt.plot(new_e, sigma(new_e, *param))
plt.plot(src_e, src_s, 'ro')
plt.savefig('1.png')
print 'Residue is:', ((sigma(src_e, *param)-src_s)**2).sum()
Residue is: 2168.65307587
```

[image]

```
In [39]:

import scipy.stats as ss
src_e[0]=0
V=ss.linregress(np.log(src_e)[1:], np.log(src_s)[1:]) #avoid log(0)
param, var = curve_fit(sigma, src_e, src_s, p0=(np.exp(V[1]), V[0]))
new_e = np.linspace(src_e.min(), src_e.max(), 50)
plt.plot(new_e, sigma(new_e, *param))
plt.plot(src_e, src_s, 'ro')
plt.savefig('1.png')
print 'Residue is:', ((sigma(src_e, *param)-src_s)**2).sum()
Residue is: 2128.85364181
```

[image]

Comment: Great thanks for your help, I will remember your approach but I will try to work with the next answer since the fitting seems to be visually better on the beginning of the curve, and it's the most important behavior in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The first point can't be on the curve, so you need to change the curve formula:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

src_s = np.array((45.59,50.66664,59.74871,65.71018,72.76012,79.06256,84.13755,90.39944,
                  96.33653,101.65667,106.27968,110.76301,114.41808,117.21922,120.51836))
src_e = np.array((0.0,0.00126,0.00503,0.00804,0.01228,0.01685,0.02127,0.02846,0.03666,
                  0.04581,0.05620,0.06882,0.08005,0.09031,0.10327))
# plot source data
plt.plot(src_e, src_s, 'o')

def sigma(e, k ,n, offset): return k*((e+offset)**n)
# find parameters curve fitting
param, var = curve_fit(sigma, src_e, src_s)
new_e = np.linspace(src_e.min(), src_e.max(), 50)
plt.plot(new_e, sigma(new_e, *param))
```

here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. The offset can be indeed an additional parameter for the target function, but it depends on experimental results. Here it seems the offset provides the best fit, and avoid zero-division error.